# MIPS - use branching instructions to rearrange the values of threeints array from smallest to greatest

Tags: architecture, mips

Using this array:

threeints:  .word 5, 255, -5

Write a program which uses branching instructions to rearrange the values of threeints such that:

the smallest value of threeints is placed into the memory location of threeints’s first element
the second smallest value of threeints is placed into the memory location of threeints’s second element
the largest value of threeints is placed to the memory location of threeints’s third element

This is my code :

```
.data
threeints:  .word 5, 255, -5

.text
main:                    
    la  $t0, threeints      # set $a0 to the address of threeints
    lw  $t1, 0($t0)         # sets $t1 to the first element in threeints
    lw  $t2, 8($t0)         # sets $t2 to the third element in threeints
    slt $t3, $t2, $t1       # $t3 = 1 (true) if $t2 < $t1
    beq $t3, $0, Else
    sw  $t1, 8($t0)         # swap
    sw  $t2, 0($t0)         # swap
    
Else:
Endif:

    lw  $t1, 4($t0)         # sets $t1 to the first element in threeints
    lw  $t2, 8($t0)         # sets $t2 to the third element in threeints
    slt $t3, $t2, $t1       # $t3 = 1 if $t2 < $t1
    beq $t3, $0, Else
    sw  $t1, 8($t0)         # swap
    sw  $t2, 4($t0)         # swap
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very minimum, you have to compare the three elements.

For two elements only, one comparison (and swap) will work

But for three elements, you need at least 4 comparisons (and three swaps).

Comment: why? im just rearranging the values from small to large, doesn't my code do that ?